# Swift - Regular Expression to match parentheses

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I am trying to use regex to search through a string: `"K1B92 (D) [56.094]"` and I want to grab the `"(D)"` including the parentheses surrounding the `"D"`.  I am having trouble finding the correct expression to match the actual parentheses as simply putting parentheses will take it as a block and trying to escape the parentheses with `"\"` making it think its an expression to be evaluated. I also tried escaping `"\("` with `"\\("` as so: `"\\([ABCD])\\)"` but without luck. This is the code I have been using:

```
let str = "K1B92 (D) [56.094]"

let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\b\\([ABCD])\\)\\b", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)

let match = regex?.firstMatchInString(str, options: NSMatchingOptions.WithoutAnchoringBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(str)))

let strRange = match?.range
let start = strRange?.location
let length = strRange?.length

let subStr = str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(str.startIndex, start!), end: advance(str.startIndex, start! + length!)))

// "\\b\([ABCD])\)\\b" returns range only for the letter "D" without parentheses.
// "\\b\\([ABCD])\\)\\b" returns nil
```

Can direct me towards the correct expression please?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>The `\\([ABCD])\\)` part is OK,</strike>
*Correction:* As @vacawama correctly said in his answer, the parentheses
do not match here. `\\([ABCD]\\)` matches one of the letters A-D
enclosed in parentheses.

The other problem is that there is no *word boundary*
(`\b` pattern) between a space and a parenthesis.

So you could either (depending on your needs), just remove the `\b` patterns, or replace them by `\s` for white space:

```
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s\\([ABCD]\\)\\s", ...
```

But since the matched string should not include the space you need
a capture group:

```
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s(\\([ABCD]\\))\\s", ...
// ...
let strRange = match?.rangeAtIndex(1)
```

Comment: I did identify her parentheses issue, which was the original question, but your answer is the most complete.  I up voted it and think it should be the accepted answer.  (comment corrected for proper pronoun usage when referring to the OP)

Comment: This solution worked perfectly.  Thank you Martin R and Vacawama for answering if so promptly. Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

The regular expression you need is `"\\([ABCD]\\)"`.  You need the double escape `\\` before both open paren `(` and close paren `)`.